# JavaScript: Write Function that take an object and an array of functions as input args and return an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, call

I want to take an object and an array of functions and return an array.  I am trying to use the for loop here.

I have the following code below:

```
const fnArr = [
      function firstName() {
        return this.first;
      },

      function lastName() {
        return this.last;
      },
    ];

const obj = { first: 'Nimit', last: 'Maru' };

function callAll(obj, fnArr){

  let newArray = [];

  for (let i=0; i<fnArr.length; i++){
    let eachFunc = fnArr[i]; 

    return newArray.push(eachFunc.call(obj))
  }
}

callAll(obj, fnArr)
```

My expected output is:

```
['Nimit', 'Maru']
```

But the output from my personal code is returning: 1

**Question 1:** What am I doing wrong here?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Additionally, the solution I was given is below:

```
const fnArr = [
          function firstName() {
            return this.first;
          },

          function lastName() {
            return this.last;
          },
        ];


const obj = { first: 'Nimit', last: 'Maru' };


const callAll = (obj, fnArr) => {
  return fnArr.map(fn => {
    return fn.call(obj);
  });
};
```

It produces the right answer.

**Question 2:** In the solution code above, why do I need the call method in "return fn.call(obj)"?

A conceptual explanation of when you need or don't need call in these types of situations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `return` stops the execution of a function, hence `return newArray.push(eachFunc.call(obj))` is wrong on it's own because it stops the loop after the first iteration. Furthermore you're returning what-ever `.push()` returns - which is the new length of the modified array;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning in each loop. So after the first loop the the function ends and code doesn't execute further.

It returns `1` because `push()` method returns the length of the array after adding elements to it. Initally array was empty when 1 element is added it returns `1`.

You don't need to necessarily use `map()` just `push()` the element(don't return). And return the `newArray` after loop.

```js
const fnArr = [
      function firstName() {
        return this.first;
      },

      function lastName() {
        return this.last;
      },
    ];

const obj = { first: 'Nimit', last: 'Maru' };

function callAll(obj, fnArr){

  let newArray = [];

  for (let i=0; i<fnArr.length; i++){
    let eachFunc = fnArr[i]; 

    newArray.push(eachFunc.call(obj))
  }
  return newArray
}


console.log(callAll(obj, fnArr))
```

> In the solution code above, why do I need the call method in "return fn.call(obj)"?

The this binding to the function depends upon how the function is called. If the function is called as the method of the object then the object will be binded to that method.

In the above code `this` inside your both functions will `refer` to `window` object if they are called normally. So we want `this` to refer the object so we use `call`

> Why eachFunc(obj) returns [undefined, undefined]?

When you don't use `call` `this` will refer to `window` object. So there is not property named `first` and `last` on `window` object so it returns `undefined`

Comment: ah! you are right, thank you;  My follow-up question is why do I need the .call() method?  eachFunc(obj) returns [undefined, undefined]

Comment: _"You don't need to necessarily use map()..."_ - Yes, but why not use something that has been implemented for exactly this purpose...

Comment: @PineNuts0 Because you're using `this` in your functions

Comment: @Andreas I said **necessarily**. New users doesnot understand higher order functions and `map()` so that's why I showed the other solution. Its necessary for programmer to know how the he can answer the question with using simple features. If a person don't understand `return`  and simple `for ` loop then its not useful to answer him using advanced features.